# At what age did Shri Krishna leave Vrindavan?

Tags: krishna, history, vrindavana

Does anyone know at what age Shri Krishna left Vrindavan?

Are there any scriptural references available for this?

Comment: Though this seems valid question I think we should not encourage such questions because people can ask for the age of same character in different timelines.

Comment: I asked question related to my above concern on meta. Here is the [link](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/267/93)

Comment: @Mr_Green I understand your concern. Although, this particular becomes important because all the Rasa Leela attributed to Krishna is before this age. I heard he left at 13, although I am not sure. If that is true, all the sexual connotations of the Leela becomes invalid. In the end, I have no issue making it a wiki if the community decides so. :)

Comment: Amit, you should mention that clearly in your question on what intention you are asking this question otherwise other users assume that they can ask questions (like small questions querying just for age) to get the age of Shri Krishna on other incidents.

Answer (score 5):

Lord Krishna Stayed in Vrindavan for **eleven years.**

Uddhava while answering the questions asked by Vidura says [this](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/2/26) verse in 3rd canto of Shrimad-Bhagavatam.

> tato nanda-vrajam itaḥ
>
> pitrā kaṁsād vibibhyatā
>
> ekādaśa samās tatra
>
> gūḍhārciḥ sa-balo ’vasat

**Translation:**

> Thereafter, His father, being afraid of Kaṁsa, brought Him to the cow
>   pastures of Mahārāja Nanda, and there He lived for eleven years like a
>   covered flame with His elder brother, Baladeva.